# How to prevent prefixes on Nest aggregations

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

It looks like Nest is somehow applying a prefix to the names of my aggregations, which can be seen on the raw JSON response back from Elastic Search (seen via `DisableDirectStreaming`). Specifically, these prefixes are `sterms#`, `dterms#`, and `range#`. These are seemingly dependant on how the aggregation in particular was made (string term, double/decimal term and range term).

I ran the same query that Nest produced, manually in Postman against ES, and it returned the aggregations without the prefixes, so I'm guessing this is as a result of a Nest specific configuration somewhere.

I would like to remove these via configuration rather than a string replace. I do not see these in the documentation so would appreciate some guidance on how to prevent these prefixes on the response object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Elastic calls these typed keys. You can find more information on them [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#return-agg-type).

To prevent the prefixes, you can set the `TypedKeys` property to `false` on the `SearchRequest`. This is not particularly well documented. This may cause adverse effects on Nest's ability to Deserialise the aggregations, so use with caution.